# hide url hashtag with jquery

Tags: jquery, url, hashtag

I need the code to hide the hashtag in the url in jQuery; I'm working on a OnePageSite and I wish to obtain "www.mysite.it" and not "www.mysite.it/index.php#hashtag" when clicking on a link.
This is a piece of code for Mootools 1.x; is there a way to make the same with jQuery?
Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('#')>-1) {
  window.location.replace(window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')));
}
```

Comment: *"I wish to obtain "www.mysite.it" and not "www.mysite.it/index.php#hashtag" when clicking on a link"* That code will give you "www.mysite.it/index.php", not "www.mysite.it".

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry. Any idea to get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

That code is JavaScript and not at all dependent on any MooTools functions, you can use it with (or without) any framework.

Comment: @bobighorus - You aren't given much context here, when is this running?